# A debugger device fails to connect to target via CAN

Tags: debugging, serial-communication, can-bus

My debug device ([UAD 2](https://www.pls-mc.com/universal-access-devices-uad-for-microcontroller-debugging-via_jtag-cjtag-dap-swd-once-lpd-dxcpl-can-asc-trace/universal_access_devices-a-797.html)) cannot establish a connection to the target over CAN port. I replaced my debug device (another UAD 2) and it works fine. Does CAN bus "error frame" bits provide information on what happened with the first debug device? I'm not sure when this error bits are written so I appreciate an expert opinion on this :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "debug device"? To my knowledge there exists no ICD debugger working over CAN, so you are apparently using some custom proprietary bootloader. In which case the question isn't related to programming. Please clarify what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: Error frames simply means that there are hardware errors. There are different kinds of error frames for different errors. You'd get stuffing errors for wrong baudrate etc.

Comment: What target are you connecting to?  Are you using the DXCPL or DXCM protocols?

Comment: @Lundin: Some devices can do proper debugger activity over the CAN physical layer: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AP3226411_DXCPL_DAP_over_CAN_Physical_Layer-AN-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624933b87501499f7192135f13&ack=t (this doesn't co-exist with actual CAN messaging, naturally :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will probably get better responses on electronics SE (but that's not an option for migration)

Comment: @MartinThompson I'd rather call that on-chip bootloader than debugger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202204/discussion-between-martin-thompson-and-lundin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAN bus error frames do not provide information about the source of errors, they only serve to inform the rest of the nodes on the bus that an error has occurred and everyone should discard the message.

Errors regarding the UAD2 (pro or next?) device will be found in the logs from the PLS tools.